# How to display external SQL table using Joomla?

Tags: extensions, mysql

I am looking for good free extensions I could use to display SQL tables on my website.

I have tried a couple but, they either don't work or ask for indexing which my tables don't have.

https://joodb.feenders.de/

JooDB has been the only one that has acutely worked on the website so far. The problem is with the free version you can only display on table on a page. The problem with is that each student has there own table wich breaks down their grade.

Also there is no simple grid view for it but that is not a big deal as its free.

Comment: Which ones have you tried? Please clarify your selection criteria and why you disqualified specific extensions.  Please [edit] your question.

Comment: What kind of display do you need, exactly? Do you just want to show a grid of columns and rows? Do you need pagination? Do you need to display the columns' meta data? Which tables are you expecting to display? Core tables or your own custom tables?

Comment: @mickmackusa I am working on a school website and need to display multiple tables of students grades.  Just need a simple grid with a search and sorting feature. I am displaying my own custom tables off PHPMyAdmin